# Details of C++ Constructor Syntax

Tags: c++, constructor

This is almost a duplicate question, but I really didn't understand the answer given for the other one, so I am going to try again:

I am learning C++ and I an trying to understand the various options for creating and using constructors. So my first question is what is the difference between these two object creations:

```
 class Example{
      Example(int x){myX = x} ;
      private:
         int myX;
 }
```

Then In my main method:

```
 Example example1 = new Example(5);
 Example example2 = Example(5);
 Example example3(5);
```

I know that using `new` will give me a dynamically allocated object, that I will later need to delete. And that the `example2` will be allocated on the stack and shouldn't need to be deleted. But I don't really understand when, or why, to use the constructor style of `example3`. any help involving minimal jargon would be very greatly appreciated because thats why I can't seem to understand this elsewhere. Thanks very much in advance for any light you guys might be able to shed on this for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two declarations

```
Example example2 = Example(5);
Example example3(5);
```

are equivalent. Although the first one *looks* like it might create an object and then invoke the copy constructor, most compilers will simply create the `example2` object in place.

The decision about when to choose which of the above styles to use is largely a matter of taste.

Here's a complete example program to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test(int x): X(x) {
        cout << "constructor " << X << endl;
    }
    Test(const Test &rhs): X(rhs.X) {
        cout << "copy " << X << endl;
    }
    Test &operator=(const Test &rhs) {
        X = rhs.X;
        cout << "assign " << X << endl;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int X;
};

int main()
{
    Test t1 = Test(1);
    Test t2(2);
    t2 = t1;
}
```

and the output (gcc 4.2.1, OS X Lion):

```
constructor 1
constructor 2
assign 1
```

Notice how the assignment operator is called only for `t2 = t1` (as expected), but the copy constructor is not called at all. (However, as Dennis Zickefoose notes in the comments, a copy constructor must be *accessible*. Try making the copy constructor `private` in the above example, and the compiler should refuse to compile it.)

EDIT: Note that `gcc` actually has an option that controls this behaviour:

```
    -fno-elide-constructors
        The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a
        temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the
        same type.  Specifying this option disables that optimization, and
        forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases.
```

Comment: Will compilers do this even if the copy constructor is non-default, i.e. overridden?  They probably shouldn't, should they--so I would imagine not...

Comment: If we overload the copy constructor, are we sure it gets called, then?

Comment: Yes, I'll add a small test program to my answer.

Comment: Is that somewhat part of the standard? The compiler is allowed to do that? I don't like when code is (not) called when the source says it should.

Comment: Thanks for the code and test--but that behavior seems totally unexpected to me!  I would expect my copy ctor to be called when declaring t1 as above.  Is this 'over-optimization' or is there a good reason for it?

Comment: I got the same output on my machine. (I'm also running lion) That is a well illustrated example, Thanks so much!

Comment: Those two statements are *not* equivalent: the first requires an accessible copy constructor, while the second does not.  The copy constructor need not be called, as you illustrate, but it still has to be present.

Answer (score 2):

```
Example example1 = new Example(5);
```

This one won't compile since `new Example(5)` returns a pointer over an `Example`. The correct usage is `Example * example1 = new Example(5)`. Needs to be deleted afterward.

```
Example example2 = Example(5);
```

This one creates a temporary Example instance and copy it to example2 using (in your case) the default copy constructor.

```
Example example3(5);
```

This one creates an instance of Example on the stack and call your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Doing both

```
className Object = className(10);
className Object(10);
```

I believe are actually equivalent. Its just personal preference.

Using `new` to create the object on the other hand besides allocating on the heap, actually returns a pointer to the created object.

```
Example* example1 = new Example(2);
```

Speaking about deletion, all of them will call the same class destructor .

Answer (score 0):

When you have an implicit constructor, you are allowed to do either:

```
class Example{
  public:
  Example(int x = 0):x(myX){} ; // use initialization list
  private:
     int myX;
};

Example example3(5); // ok
Example example3 = 5; // ok
```

Note that, the constructor that I defined *also* serves as a **default** constructor.

To be more specific, constructor style in example 3 is usually a case when your constructor is explicit.

```
class Example{
  public:
  explicit Example(int x = 0):x(myX){} ; // use initialization list
  private:
     int myX;
};

Example example3(5); // ok
Example example3 = 5; // not allowed
```

You might want to read this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) for more information on the use of initialization list in constructor.